# Узнать, пересекаются ли отрезки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, геометрия

Отрезки могут быть горизонтальные или вертикальные.
У меня есть верхняя точка отрезка(если он вертикальный) и левая(если он горизонтальный) и длина отрезка.
Как узнать, пересекаются ли они?

Answer (score 1):

Если за математику то я готов ответить)

1) Вычислить оба конца обоих отрезков

2) Построить уравнения прямых (у вас они вообще простые y=cont, x=const)

3) Подставить первый конец первого отрезка во второе уравнение, запомнить знак
Поставить второй конц первого отрезка во второе уравнение знак должен быть противоположен предыдущему

4) Проверить тоже что и в п.3 только поменять местами уравнения и концы (т.е. концы второго отрезка уравнение первого), знаки снова должны сменится при подстановки разных концов.

Если всё так, то отрезки пересекаются, так можно для любых отрезков проверить (даже наклонных).

Comment: А как мне подставить координаты вершины в уравнение второй прямой, если там или y=const, или x=const?

Comment: Ну так и подставьте то что есть (если y=const, то y, если x=const, то x). Ведь очевидно что уравнение не зависит от второй координаты.

Comment: Можно, но несколько сложновато...

Answer (score 0):

Представить отрезки как вырожденные прямоугольники 4 значениями (left, top, right, bottom), а потом попытаться пересечь - при оси y, направленной вниз получится:

```
max(l1, l2) <= min(r1, r2) && max(t1, t2) <= min(b1, b2)
```

Если вверх, то аналогично.